# How can I use stackless python on heroku?

Tags: heroku, python-stackless

I'm trying to use stackless python for a heroku app, but they don't support the runtime:

```
!     Requested runtime (stackless-3.3.5) was not found.
```

This is surprising, since stackless-3.3.5 was recently added to the list of "unofficial" releases that are available on the heroku buildpack.

[heroku python versions](https://github.com/kennethreitz/python-versions/tree/master/formula)